# How to know what type of authentication to use with Python Requests

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

Python's requests library can access websites with [different types of authentication](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/).
For example, I have an account with [coderbyte](https://coderbyte.com/sl). I want to write a Python script to scrape data from a table (that I can view after logging in) with results from a coding test.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
URL = 'https://coderbyte.com/dashboard/ishangoai-nx1aa:data-science-as-ypd9gqutaz'
page = requests.get(URL, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('name@me.com', 'MyPassword'))
print(page.text)
```

The above code returns:
`You do not have permission to access this page. Please <a href="https://coderbyte.com/sl-org">click here to log in</a>.`

However there are many different types of authentication used on websites, so I'm not sure which one of requests authentication capabilities to use.

Comment: AFAIK, the most common type of authentication consists of filling and submitting a form with your login and password. This is usually done with a simple HTTP POST request